# Batch cmd MKDIR folder with a name including symbol

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mkdir

I would like use command batch to create list folder.

But the name of folder include symbol characters, I don't know how to use cmd batch

Ex: I would like create list folder

```
01.DOCUMENT
02.SOURCE
03.DESIGN
04.TEST
05.REPORT
06....
```

Input: Input root-directory(strfolder)

Then example use: mkdir %strfolder%\ (+ name folder 01.Ducment,...) but I don't know use

My current code:

```
@echo off
cls
set /p folderName=Enter project name:%=%
@echo %folderName%

SET mypath=%~dp0
rem echo %mypath:~0,-1%

set folder=%mypath%%folderName%


if exist %folder% (
    echo "Folder already exists"
) else (
    mkdir %folder%
    rem mkdir %folder%\%1 %RELEASE% --> this line don't know how :D
    echo %folder%\%^1%
)

pause
```

Comment: Please don't type your question title in ALL CAPS. It makes it harder to read, it's annoying, and it won't help you get an answer any faster. Thanks. :-) It's also very unclear what you're asking, because you've shown no example of how you're trying to use `mkdir` or anything with a "symbol". You should probably [edit] your question to include more information, including what you've tried so far that isn't working, if you want people here to help you.

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to quote your target if it contains symbols:

```
mkdir "%folder%"
```

(`md` is the same as `mkdir`)

Also:
    mkdir "%folder%" 2>nul

will create the directory; the `2>nul` suppresses the error message.

`%release%` appears from nowhere. You don't say what it is or where it comes from; then you `REM` it anyway. No iea of what is happening there.

Now if your directory-names are in a file then

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filename.txt) do echo %%i
```

should show you the names. If you want to create subdirectories using these names then

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filename.txt) do echo MD "%folder%\%%i"
```

should do that for you - well, would `ECHO` the command; remove the `ECHO` keyword to actually make the directory.

Note that virtually any character would be happy so long as it remains in the metavariable `%%i` used as a loop-control. Some less-frequently-used characters can present a problem within an ordingary %variable%.

If your data contains parentheses, then the parser may become confused about whether a parenthesis is part of the command or the data. Best to avoid parenthesised constructs if that is the case.